# Lech Lecha: Avraham fulfilled G-ds mitzvos with joy

Tags: sources-mekorot, commentaries, abraham, parashat-lech-lecha, faith-bitachon-emunah

Rabbi Yerucham Brodianski in his sefer [Siach Yitzchak (Parashas Vayigash, p. 480, sv. תשמע לאומרים)](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=60786&st=&pgnum=492) quotes the Nesivos Shalom and says that bitachon in Hashem will give a person inner joy when performing a mitzvah.

This got me thinking about what the Torah relates about Avraham Avinu, when he was first called upon by G-d.

G-d said to Avraham Avinu:

> לך לך - Get thee out of thy country [...] אֶל-הָאָרֶץ, אֲשֶׁר אַרְאֶךָּ - To the land that I will show you (parashas Lech Lecha, Bereishis 12:1)

Avraham Avinu immediately "packed his bags" and did what Hashem told him to do. See [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/57217/27180) answer where this idea is somewhat echoed.

Avraham Avinu had the bitachon in Hashem that He would lead him the way, and that he was in good hands.

But, are there meforshim that stress the fact that Avraham Avinu was praised for his outstanding level of bitachon in Hashem and that he fullfilled the mitzvos with simcha (joy)? Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Midrash Tehillim 112:1:

> Abraham fulfilled the entire Torah from Aleph to Tav, as it is written, "Because Abraham obeyed me and did everything I required of him, keeping my commands, my decrees and my instructions" (Genesis 26:5). Therefore, the psalm of ascent is said about him, from Aleph to Tav, along with the psalm of his wife, from Mem to Tav, "Praiseworthy is the woman who fears the Lord" (Proverbs 31:30). And both of them fulfilled the entire Torah from Aleph to Tav. Praiseworthy is the person who fears the Lord, and why is he praised? Because **he did not perform the commandments with anguish, but with joy and with great desire**.

Comment: Great find, Maurice. Thanks!